# why my code works in the second situation but not in the first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, addeventlistener, document

I want to know for what reason the programme is working in the second case but not in the first one.

CASE1:-

```
let tem=document.getElementById('timed').value
let timeBtn=document.getElementById('timed_input');
timeBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    console.log(tem);
})
```

CASE2:-

```
let timeBtn=document.getElementById('timed_input');
timeBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    console.log(document.getElementById('timed').value);
})
```

Comment: In the first case you're getting the value once, and then printing that same value on every click. In the second case, you get an up-to-date value on every click.

Answer (score 0):

Because value is very likely to be a [primitive data type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive). When you assign a primitive value to a variable, the value is copied to the variable. In contrast, when you assign an object to a variable, you get a reference of the object and not a copy of it.

Take a look at this example.

```
let a = 20;
let b = a;
a = 30;
console.log(a); // 30
console.log(b); // 20
```

Even though we assign `let b = a`, we stored the value of a (20) into b, b and a don't have a relation to each other.

In contrast with non primitive data types, like objects:

```
let a = { name: "Doria", age: 22 };
let b = a;
b.name = "Nicole";
console.log(a.name); // Nicole
console.log(b.name); // Nicole
```

In this case, a and b are related, in the sense that they are referencing the same object.